# Refresh google map after enabling location

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am using **ng-cordova geolocation** and **javascript google maps api** to get user's current location in my ionic app **(ionic 1)** .

If the location settings is not enabled I inform the user that it should be.
When the user enables the location settings, the map stays blank. I have to reload the page to let the map load.

**How can I detect that the location setting is changed and then refresh the map automatically?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) registers a function to be called when a change in Location state occurs.

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler(successCallback);
```

This is triggered when Location state changes, so this is useful for detecting changes made in quick settings which would not result in pause/resume events being fired.

In the [official documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#registerlocationstatechangehandler) of that plugin, you can find some examples and more information about how to implement.

Keep rocking!